# CAAnimation not animating my sequence of images

Tags: objective-c, caanimation

I'm having trouble with animating with CAAnimation, it doesn't seem to give me any errors but it isn't animating. I'm confused

```
NSMutableArray *animationImages = [NSMutableArray array];
//Adding images into array
for (int i=0;i<=5;i++){
    UIImage *imgfile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/ConusOverlay/%d_ConusOverlay.gif",documentsPath,i];
    [animationImages addObject: imgfile];
}

CAKeyframeAnimation *animationSequence = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"contents"];
animationSequence.calculationMode = kCAAnimationLinear;
animationSequence.autoreverses = NO;
animationSequence.duration = 1;
animationSequence.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;

NSMutableArray *animationSequenceArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (UIImage *image in animationImages) {
    [animationSequenceArray addObject:image]; //<--Does this have to be (id)image.CGImage ?, if I am correct you are unable to add CGImage to an array
}
animationSequence.values = animationSequenceArray;
[mlLayer.contents addAnimation:animationSequence forKey:@"contents"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreAnimation usually takes `CGImageRef`s and not `UIImages`. Try replacing the `image` with the `(id)image.CGImage` as you suggested. Arrays can store `CGImageRef`s!

Comment: Thank you very much this worked, I changed [animationSequenceArray addObject:image] to [animationSequenceArray addObject:(id)image.CGImage. Works Beautifully, Thanks again.